# Load css on condition

Tags: magento2, css, if

I need to a CSS file based on customer attribute when the user is logged.

How can I do this ?

Readed this : https://mage2.pro/t/topic/140 but it's based on backend config.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution : If it helps, i've added a event in my **event.xml**

```
<event name="controller_action_predispatch">
    <observer name="addCSS" instance="Vendore\Module\Observer\AddCSS" shared="false" />
</event>
```

the related observer :

```
public function execute(Observer $observer){
    $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $page = $om->get('Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config');

    $condition = $this->getConditionResult();
    if($condition){
        $page->addPageAsset('Magento_Theme::css/otherCSS.css');
    }
}
```

Comment: @all This should be `events.xml`, not `event.xml` (etc/frontend/* or etc/* or etc/adminhtml/*)